# "void value not ignored as it ought to be" when use gcc

Tags: c, gcc

here is my code in gcc c99, where have "void value" in my code?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *s = "smth";
    int r2 = ({ if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(s), char*)) { true; } else { false; }});
    return (0);
};
```

**update**

even worse, following code has same error

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *s = "smth";
    int r2 = ({if (1) {1;} else {0;}});
    return (0);
};
```

Comment: 1) That is awful for multiple reasons. 2) What do you think a selection statement shall return? - Anyway, that is not standard compliant 3) Why not stick to the standard and use a conditional expression - or 4) You do not need a conditional construct at all.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to assign an `if` statement to an `int`.  That statement doesn't have a type, hence why you're seeing the error.

What you want instead is the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation):

```
condition ? true_value : false_valse
```

If `condition` evaluates to true, the expression has the value of `true_value`, otherwise it has the value of `false_value`.

So what you want is this:

```
int r2 = (__builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(s), char*)) ? true : false;
```

Or, since the two values are simply `true` and `false`:

```
int r2 = __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(s), char*);
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
if (condition) {statement}
```

will return `void` and you can't be used to initialize/assign a variable. Better to use ternary operator `?:`

```
int r2 = __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(s), char*) ? true : false
```

or better

```
bool r2 = __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(s), char*)  // Use stdbool.h
```

because [`__builtin_types_compatible_p`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) returns `1` if the given types are same, otherwise returns `0`.

Comment: 1) Why not use `bool` when already initialising with boolean constants? 2) Why a conditional something at all? Just `bool r2 = __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(s), char*)` is sufficient and much clearer (and it should have a self-explanatory name).